# Dynamic import in NodeJS (in Gatsby): A dynamic import callback was not specified

Tags: node.js, import, gatsby, dynamic-import

I'm trying to use the dynamic imports in NodeJS, with a eS6 file, but can't get it work

I'm using it in a `gatsby` project within its `gatsby-node.js` file

```js
exports.createPages = async props => {
  
  //...

  const name = './test'
  ;(async () => {
    const data = await import(name)
    console.log(data)
  })()
```

Where `test.js` is just

```js
export const hey = 'hi'
```

But I always get this `A dynamic import callback was not specified.`

Why is it not working? NodeJS version is `12.18.4`

Answer (score 0):

## Update (11th of November 2022)

The syntax should be valid without importing any additional plugins with Babel.

If you need them or need to tweak/customize its configuration, please continue reading.

---

Since it's not currently a publish version, you need to install each desired module ([`babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import) in your case) of ES6 and add it yo your babel configuration.

Run:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

Then, in your Babel file (`babel.config.js` or `.babelrc` in the root of your project) add it to `plugins` array:

```
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
```

Ideally, your Babel file should look like:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    [`@babel/preset-env`, { 'useBuiltIns': `usage`, 'corejs': `2` }],
    [`@babel/preset-react`, { 'development': true, minify: true }],
  ];

  const plugins = [
    `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`,
  ];

  return { presets, plugins };
};
```

Comment: I'm using `.babelrc`, there I've added the plugin (after installing it), but the babel conf is the one provided by Gatsby, which however should be equivalent to the one you suggested (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-gatsby). Yet, I'm still getting the same error message :(